# Node.js cluster + collective

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have submitted the issue to the  [github repo](https://github.com/arch1t3ct/collective.js/issues/3), so as to track it there!

I'm running a clustered app that could be on a machine with N cores. Let's say I am running 2 of the app instances locally for testing, really emulating 2 different boxes. So N cores on N machines using the `cluster` module (in reality, the N machines is static, e.g. just 2 behind an AWS Load Balancer).

1. How do I properly configure the [collective.js](https://github.com/arch1t3ct/collective.js) "all_hosts" option for this? Would I use `process.id` somehow along with IP?

Running the code snippets would be something along the lines of 2 bash terminals:

*terminal 1*:

`coffee cluster1`

*terminal 2*:

`coffee cluster2`

Note: the code below works, but doesn't *really* work, as I can't quite figure out the configuration; each time I log data it's specific to the process.

**cluster1.coffee**:

```
cluster = require 'cluster'
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

if cluster.isMaster

  i = 0 
  cluster.setupMaster 
    exec: './server1'

  console.log "App 1 clustering with: #{numCPUs} clusters"

  while i < numCPUs
    cluster.fork()
    i++

  cluster.on 'fork', (worker) ->
    console.log 'Forked App 1 server worker ' + worker.process.pid
```

**server1.coffee**:

```
Collective = require 'collective'

all_hosts = [
    host: 'localhost', port: 8124 # Wrong
]

collective = new Collective(
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 8124
, all_hosts, (collective) ->

)

collectiveUpsert = () ->

  num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1)

  data = 
    num: num

  console.log process.pid + ' sees current num as: ' + JSON.stringify(collective.get('foo.bar'))
  console.log process.pid + ' setting num to: ' + JSON.stringify(data)

  collective.set 'foo.bar', data

setInterval (->
  collectiveUpsert()
), 5 * 1000
```

**cluster2.coffee**:

```
cluster = require 'cluster'
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

if cluster.isMaster

  i = 0 
  cluster.setupMaster 
    exec: './server2'

  console.log "App 2 clustering with: #{numCPUs} clusters"

  while i < numCPUs
    cluster.fork()
    i++

  cluster.on 'fork', (worker) ->
    console.log 'Forked App 2 server worker ' + worker.process.pid
```

**server2.coffee**:

```
Collective = require 'collective'

all_hosts = [
    host: 'localhost', port: 8124 # Wrong
]

collective = new Collective(
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 8124
, all_hosts, (collective) ->

)

collectiveUpsert = () ->

  num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1)

  data = 
    num: num

  console.log process.pid + ' sees current num as: ' + JSON.stringify(collective.get('foo.bar'))
  console.log process.pid + ' setting num to: ' + JSON.stringify(data)

  collective.set 'foo.bar', data

setInterval (->
  collectiveUpsert()
), 5 * 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use [collective.js](https://github.com/arch1t3ct/collective.js) with `cluster` and/or multiple servers you need to start it on every Node.js child process. Think of it as a `http` module, where you have to create the listener on every child/slave, not the master (http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster). Following similar logic, for collective.js, you should do something like this (single server):

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // fork n children
} else {
    var current_host = {host: "localhost", port: 10000};
    current_host.port += cluster.worker.id; // this is incremented for every new process.

    var all_hosts = [
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10001},
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10002},
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10003},
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10004},
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10005},
        {"host": "localhost", "port": 10006}
        // must be the same amount as is the child process count.
    ];

    var collective = new modules.collective(current_host, all_hosts, function (collective) {
        // Do your usual stuff. Start http listener, etc...
    });
}
```

You should modify *localhost* to your ip addresses and make sure ports increment properly, if you want to use this on different servers.

For any additional information you can check crude tests at [test/index.js](https://github.com/arch1t3ct/collective.js/blob/master/test/index.js)

Hope that helps! If you need any further assistance - please ask.

P.S. Admittedly, this way is to cumbersome and needs clearer explanation. I hope to figure out a cleaner and easier initialization process in the near future. In addition to that, clarify the readme and provide some full examples.